# Input capture on iOS image rotation

Tags: php, ios, input

I am struggling with my php form. I want to upload image via input capture function. But the image is rotated after capturing the img on iOS device. I have found tons of articles about exif but notihing worked for me. So I am pasting my code below and I would like to ask for help how to implement the code for rotation to the rest of the code. (I have no idea how to do it.) Thx bros for help. Or maybe any suggestions?
Code to implement:

```
fileReader.onloadend = function() {

var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));

switch(exif.Orientation){

   case 8:
       ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
       break;
   case 3:
       ctx.rotate(180*Math.PI/180);
       break;
   case 6:
       ctx.rotate(-90*Math.PI/180);
       break;


}};
```

the rest:

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['title']) or empty($_POST['shop']) or empty($_FILES['image']) or empty($_POST['price'])) {
        echo "All fields must be filled";
    } 
    else {
        $userID = $_POST['userID'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $price_before = $_POST['price_before'];
        $town = $_POST['town'];
        $shop = $_POST['shop'];

        if(empty($_POST['price_before'])){
            $price_before = null;
        }
        if(empty($_POST['cut'])){
            $pcut = null;
        }
        if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
            $errors = array();
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name'])));
            $expensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            if (in_array($file_ext, $expensions) === false) {
                $errors[] = "extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
            }
            if ($file_size > 8097152) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 8 MB';
            }
            if (empty($errors) == true) {
                session_start();
                $hour = date("H");
                $min = date("i");
                $sec = date("s");
                $day = date("d");
                $month = date("m");
                $year = date("Y");

                $url = "../pic/".$file_name.".".$file_ext;

                $file_name = md5(uniqid());



                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "../pic/".$file_name.".".$file_ext);

                $upload = "INSERT INTO item (userID, title, price, price_before, town, shop, img_name, img_ext, hour, min, sec, day, month, year) VALUES ('$userID', '$title', '$price',' $price_before', '$town', '$shop', '$file_name', '$file_ext', '$hour', '$min', '$sec', '$day', '$month', '$year' )";



                $result = $conn -> query($upload);
                 echo '<div style=width:100%;height:100%;display:flex;margin:0;>
   <div style=width:auto;height:auto%;vertical-align:middle;margin:auto;><div class="cssload-spin-box"></div></div></div>';
header('Refresh: 2; URL = ../index.php');
                } else {
                    print_r($errors);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. So here is the `UIImage` extension.

```
extension UIImage {

   /// (Additional method to fix the image orientation issue on b/w server and client)
   public func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {
   if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up {
       return self
   }

   var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

   switch self.imageOrientation {
   case .Down, .DownMirrored:
       transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height)
       transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI));

   case .Left, .LeftMirrored:
       transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
       transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2));

   case .Right, .RightMirrored:
       transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
       transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2));

   case .Up, .UpMirrored:
       break
   }

   switch self.imageOrientation {

   case .UpMirrored, .DownMirrored:
       transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
       transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)

   case .LeftMirrored, .RightMirrored:
       transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0)
       transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);

   default:
       break;
   }

   // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
   // calculated above.
   let ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(
       nil,
       Int(self.size.width),
       Int(self.size.height),
       CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage),
       0,
       CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
       UInt32(CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage).rawValue)
   )

   CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);

   switch self.imageOrientation {
   case .Left, .LeftMirrored, .Right, .RightMirrored:
       // Grr...
       CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);

   default:
       CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
       break;
   }

   // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
   let cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)

   let img = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg!)

   return img;
 }
}
```

**Now fix the image orientation before sending it to server**

```
let imageToUpload = originalImage.fixOrientation()
```

**NOTE: Don't remove EXIF data as it holds the orientation property.**

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be helpfull, but please can you tell me how to implement it ? I am not such a pro.

Comment: @IgorMiniMinarič This is swift language code and will be implement at iOS side. But I guess you are asking for PHP code. Sorry brother.

Answer (score 0):

I made a huge research on web and this code finaly worked perfect. Basically I had to save the img in to directory and then open dir and do this magic. This is I guess most easy way how to fix iOS orientation camera problem.

```
 $buffer = ImageCreateFromJPEG($url); //url is path to image
$exif =@exif_read_data($url);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])){
    switch($exif['Orientation']){
        case 8:
            $buffer = imagerotate($buffer,90,0);
        break;
        case 3:
            $buffer = imagerotate($buffer,180,0);
        break;
        case 6:
            $buffer = imagerotate($buffer,-90,0);
        break;
    }
}

imagejpeg($buffer, $url, 90);
```